# How to disable text input in textarea

Tags: html, css, web

I just need to disable typing any text into text-area, I want to use text-area just for showing text. I am making a chat web-site.

Comment: Show us what you have to help.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_disabled.asp

Answer (score 14):

You can just add `readonly`

```html
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor.</textarea>
```

Comment: Why placeholder? I tried without that and it works, btw I am from Balkan too

Comment: Yes you don't need to use placeholder, also if you don't want textarea to be gray you can use css to change that https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/593/

Comment: The advantage of `readonly` over `disabled` is that we can programmatically copy the content to the clipboard

Answer (score 1):

For `Angular` applications use following syntax, it will not allow any `pointer events` but we can `scroll` the context

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" [readonly]="true/false">{{info}}</textarea>
```

Comment: This works for React too, and without the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_disabled.asp) attribute for this

You can style this in CSS

Or If you want only to show text use `div` or `span` not `textarea`